# How to add a sparse vector as a column to Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to add a (1*8) sparse vector as a column to the Pyspark dataframe.
The dataframe and my expected dataframe are as followed:

```
id  timestamp   v_row   v_col   v_val
19  1/17/19 0:00    0   1   0.1
19  1/17/19 0:00    0   3   0.2
19  1/17/19 0:00    0   4   0.3
19  1/17/19 0:00    0   6   0.4
19  1/17/19 0:05    0   2   0.25
19  1/17/19 0:05    0   3   0.4
19  1/17/19 0:05    0   4   0.1
19  1/17/19 0:05    0   5   0.2
19  1/17/19 0:05    0   7   0.05
```

```
id  timestamp   sparse_vector       
19  1/17/19 0:00    [[0, 0.1, 0, 0.2, 0.3, 0, 0.4, 0]]      
19  1/17/19 0:05    [[0, 0, 0.25, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0, 0.05]]
```

![enter image description here][1]

I used `udf` with `sparse.coo_matrix` to return a matrix, and this is my code that doesn't work. Can anyone help me find my bugs?

```
def sparse_vector(data, val):

    pd_df = data.toPandas()

    rows = np.array( pd_df['v_row'] )
    cols = np.array( pd_df['v_col'])
    vals = np.array( pd_df[val] )

    V = sparse.coo_matrix((vals, (rows, cols)), shape = (1, 8)).toarray().tolist()

    return V

window = Window.partitionBy(['user_id', 'timestamp'])
sparse_vector_udf = F.udf(sparse_vector, ArrayType(ArrayType(FloatType())))
y2 = y1.withColumn('vector', sparse_vector_udf(y1, 'v_val').over(window))
```

Answer (score 0):

Following [Spark MLlib documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#module-pyspark.ml.linalg), this is how you create a `SparseVector` in a dataframe

```py
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1.0, Vectors.dense(1.0), 1.0),
    (1e-40, Vectors.sparse(1, [], []), 0.0)], ["label", "features", "censor"])

df.show()

# +-------+---------+------+
# |  label| features|censor|
# +-------+---------+------+
# |    1.0|    [1.0]|   1.0|
# |1.0E-40|(1,[],[])|   0.0|
# +-------+---------+------+

# root
#  |-- label: double (nullable = true)
#  |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
#  |-- censor: double (nullable = true)
```